# Web Scraping Data Visualization

Tags: python, numpy, web-scraping, formatting, data-visualization

I'm trying to capture **AND** present data in a table format after the script is finished. The website I am using is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_all-time_NFL_win-loss_records And the logic is working as such:

1. I run the command, it opens to the URL
2. I then go to the URL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_all-time_NFL_win-loss_records
3. I proceed to copy any selected rows/columns from the Table/chart
4. I then go back to my IDE (Jupyter Notebook) and it takes the captured data and spits it out

I can select the data on that particular webpage and copy it using my cursor by highlighting and selecting “copy”. It will then spit out all that I have selected and copied to my clipboard.

So far, my script that I wrote, is working to only capture the data and then spit it back out as is (unformatted).

**PROBLEM**: I would like the data I captured to be presented in a table format **after** I have finished selecting it and have it copied in my clipboard.

I realize I need to probably write the logic for the data I captured to be then be formatted. What would be the best approach for accomplishing this?

Below is my code that I have written so far:

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
Import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, Dataframe
website='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFL_win_loss_records'
web browser.open(website)
nfl_frame= pd.read_clipboard(Sep='\t')
nfl_frame
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read your data directly to DataFrame with `pandas.read_html`

```py
import pandas as pd

WIKI_URL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_all-time_NFL_win-loss_records'
df = pd.read_html(WIKI_URL,header=0)[1] 

df.head() # in jupyter or print(df.head()) to show a table with first 5 rows
```

As `pd.read_html` returns a list. In them are tables that are in that HTML/URL. I set header to first raw, and selected the second element of the list which is the table you are looking for.